# What comes next? For 8 year olds. Part II

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

This question is from the homework of my niece. She is 8 years old. And I could not help her with this question.

There is a sequence of numbers. Problem asks the sum of the next two numbers. And result is one of 232, 311, 343, 434. I couldn't find a rule for the sequence.

```
7, 10, 15, 23, 34, 53, 83, A, B

A + B = ?
```

Any ideas?

Spoiler:
My best guess is as follows. And I am not sure whether this is the correct rule or the answer.

```
7 + 10 = 17 AND 17 - 2 = 15 => 2
10 + 15 = 25 AND 25 - 2 = 23 => 2
15 + 23 = 38 AND 38 - 4 = 34 => 4
23 + 34 = 57 AND 57 - 4 = 53 => 4
34 + 53 = 87 AND 87 - 4 = 83 => 4
```

Therefore

```
53 + 83 = 136 AND 136 - 4 = 132 = A (4)
83 + 132 = 215 AND 215 - 4 = 211 = B (4)  

A + B = 343
```

But I couldn't explain why the fifth one also uses 4 for the subtraction.

Comment: The differences are $3,5,8=3+5,11=3+8,19=8+11,30=11+19$; $11$ seems to be an odd one!

Comment: I've also noticed that.

Comment: It is not featured in the OEIS, so it is boring.

Answer (score 2):

Consecutive differences are $$3, 5, 8, 11, 19, 30$$

---

Notice that

$$3+5 = 8$$ 
$$3 + 8 = 11$$ 
$$8 + 11 = 19$$ 
$$11+19 = 30$$

---

The next three differences should be 
$$11 + 30$$
$$30 + (11 + 30)$$
$$(11 + 30) + (30 + (11 + 30))$$

---

This gives $$A = 83 + 11 + 30 = 124$$
and

$$B = A + 30 + 11 + 30 = 195$$

Finally, we have $$A + B = \boxed{319}$$

---

I don't like these problems because if you try hard enough, you can find a pattern that justifies *anything you want* coming next, as in [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Comment: Sorry but 319 is not even an answer candidate for the question (result is one of 232, 311, 343, 434). As I told before maybe the question is wrong. And by the way if the differences were 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, it would make sense but this way, I don't know :|

Answer (score 1):

The differences between consecutive numbers is increasing:

> $$7, 10, 15, 23, 34, 53, 83, A, B$$

---

Sequence of differences:

$$3, 5, 8, 11, 19, 30.$$

---

So my guesses are:

$$A=83+30+19 = 132$$

and

$$B=A+49+30 =211$$

And therefore $$A+B=343$$

Comment: The problem with this answer is 11. All the other differences are the sum of the two previous ones (Except 3 and 5 of course). As I said before, maybe there is a mistake in the question. I am going to ask to the teacher who gave this question as a homework :)